# brackets and js expressions executiing

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain me this expressions and how it works:

```
(1, 2, 3) //returns  3
```

next:

```
var foo = 0, bar = 'baz';
   (foo++,foo++, bar) // foo = 2, returns 'baz'
```

and:

```
var f = (function f(){ return "1"; }, function g(){ return 2; })();
typeof f; // returns number
```

As i undestand expressions inside brackers executings from left to right and then returning the last item? If so, why the last example returns number?? After the executing `function f(){ return "1"; }` it cought return string...

Comment: Because its executing the `g` at last

Comment: If you agree that `(1, 2, 3)` returns the last item, why are you expecting the first function (`f`) to be the result of your final example?

Comment: those are not brackets n_n those are parentheses

Comment: It's beacuse You are using the **comma operator**, the parentheses are not important. See here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(x, y, z)` expression simply evaluates the arguments and return the last argument.
So in case `(1, 2, 3)` `1` is evaluated to 1, `2` is evaluated to 2, `3` is evaluated to 3 and it is returned.

**Now in your second example:**

`var foo = 0, bar = 'baz';
   (foo++,foo++, bar) // foo = 2, returns 'baz'`

it returns `baz` as `bar` is the last argument evaluated and returned. Meanwhile both `foo++` are evaluated but not returned thus giving you foo value of `2`.

**NOW your last example** is really simple but please don't use such an agony in practice.
Let me simplify your expression into:

`var f = (function f(){ return "1"; }, function g(){ return 2; })`

By making it not self-executing. The first function is evaluated - good, the second is evaluated and returned. Now your `f` is simply `function g()`. As you wrap everything in `()` and immediately execute with another `()` you are simply doing `g()`.

Let me break down the things a bit:

`var f = (function f(){ return "1"; }, function g(){ return 2; })`

1. `f` is equal to `function g() { return 2; }`
2. `(f)()` returns the function f and immediately executes it thus giving you `2` whith type is of course a `Number`.

Comment: i got this question after this [quiz](http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/)

Answer (score 1):

When you list multiple expressions separated by a comma, the last one is the result.

```
(function f(){}, function g(){});  // returns g
```

Then you're executing the returned function.

```
(...)(); // executes the function returned in parens
```

Your function `g` returns `2`, a number.